# Validate a form with multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have a form that has multiple elements/types

1. inputs for name, email, address, etc.
2. radio button for shipping speed.
3. select tags for "state" & "credit card type".

I want to disable the submit button until the:

1.inputs are filled out.

2. the select tags have an option selected
3. the radio is checked.

I've selected the elements (see below);

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#olegnax-osc-place-order-button');

let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#olegnax-osc-billing-address-list .required-entry, input#authorizenet_cc_number');
let selectTags = document.querySelectorAll('#olegnax-osc-billing-address-list select, #payment_form_authorizenet select');
let radio = document.querySelector('#s_method_owebiashipping1_id_06');
```

My question is, being the form consists of 3 different types (input, select, radio), can I just create one array with all of these elements and loop though to make sure the value for each is not blank?

For example, say I store all the different elements in an array called "requiredFields" would this work?:

```
for (var i = 0; i < requiredFeilds.length; i++) {
  if (requiredFeilds[i].value === '') {
    btn.disabled = true;
  }else {
    btn.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more to form validation than meets the eye, but that being said you have a major flaw in your logic.  Namely, as you loop over all the fields, you could be changing `btn.disabled` back and forth depending on the value of the form field (or lack of a value).

Instead, begin with the button disabled, and then instead of looping, use Array.prototype.some (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any field is missing a value, something such as:

```
btn.disabled = requiredFields.some(field => field === '');
```

There's lots else to address with regards to your approach but this corrects your current logic error and is much more concise.

Comment: Thanks, "validate" was probably the wrong term to use as I really just need the button disabled until all fields have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through everything but the radio buttons easily. For the radio buttons, you want to check if any of the buttons *in a radio group* are checked, so it is a little more complicated. It might be easier to just designate a radio button as default, with the `checked` attribute:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = true;
const inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.forms["form1"].querySelectorAll("input[type=text], select"));

document.forms["form1"].addEventListener("input", () => {
  let complete = true;
  
  inputs.forEach((field) => {
    if(field.value.trim() === "") {
      complete = false;
    }
  });

document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = !complete;
});
```

```css
form{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="bar" />
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <select name="biz">
    <option disabled selected value>---</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
  <select name="baz">
    <option disabled selected value>---</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
  <label>
  A <input type="radio" name="buzz" value="a" checked /> 
  </label>
  <label>
  B <input type="radio" name="buzz" value="b" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just combine your selectors and use a comma, and check `tagName`:

```
const requiredFields = document.querySelectorAll( "
   #olegnax-osc-place-order-button,
   #olegnax-osc-billing-address-list .required-entry,
   input#authorizenet_cc_number,
   #olegnax-osc-billing-address-list select,
   #payment_form_authorizenet select,
   #s_method_owebiashipping1_id_06
" );

for( let input of requiredFields ) {

    if( input.tagName == "INPUT" ) {

    }
    else if( input.tagName == "SELECT" ) {

    }
    else if( input.tagName == "TEXTAREA" ) {

    }
}
```

You should also use the `required` attribute too:

```
<input type="text" required />
<select required></select>
<textarea required></textarea>
```